# How to ensure both scale and slide up can occur for dynamic text using css and js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

Please find this CodePen: http://codepen.io/hellouniverse/pen/rrVddV

I have a sample image and text that is obtained using an `Ajax` call. I cannot show the Ajax call, so on the CodePen I have included a mimic that tried to make as similar as I could. The text is dynamically added after the image.

When hovered, I want to ensure that there is a zoom effect on the image and also have the text slide up nicely. **Right now, the zoom kind of works, while the text does not slide up, but basically jumps to the top!!!**

I cannot get it working no matter how many coffees I drink or how many times I swear at IntelliJ. I must be making a very minor mistake somewhere and would appreciate any help.

Basically, I want to do the following **on hover**:

- The text slides up on hover and slides down on mouse out
- The image has a zoom effect (at scale 1.1) on hover and scales back on mouse out
- Also, the width and the height of the div (block__Content) should not increase at all (but is currently expanding because of the scale).

```js
 var $title = "MY Title";
 var $summary = "My Summary";
 var $ctaText = "A CTA TEXT";
 // Here is the mimic I described;
 // The data is actually obtained using an Ajax call (which I cannot replicate here):
 var $contentHover = "<div class='content-added contenthover'></div>";

 $('.myImage').after($contentHover); // Add the div that will be targeted for the hover

 var $contentHoverHeader = "<h2 class='contenthover__header'>" + $title + '</h2>';
 var $contentHoverContent = "<p class='contenthover__content'>" + $summary + '</p>';
 var $contentHoverLink = "<a class='contenthover__link' href='#'>" + $ctaText + '</a>';

 $('.contenthover').append($contentHoverHeader, $contentHoverContent, $contentHoverLink);
 $('.contenthover').hover(function() {

   $('.contenthover').css({
     display: 'inline-block',
     width: '100%',
     height: '278px',
     position: 'absolute',
     bottom: '0',
     transition: 'bottom 500ms ease-out'
   })
 });
```

```css
.block__content {
  max-width: 1280;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.block__content {
  width: auto;
  height: 278px;
}
.contenthover {
  display: none;
}
.bgtile {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  &: hover, &: focus {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 278px;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  }
}
.node__content {
  span {
    display: none;
    // NO to the text } }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block__content">
  <div class="content-tile">
    <article role="article" class="node sb-article bgtile" style="background-image: url('http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg');">
      <div class="node__content">
        <span>DO NOT DISPLAY ME</span>
        <div class="myImage">
          <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg" alt="A large image" typeof="Image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little change in your *CSS* and *jQuery* will lead you to achieve this easily.

Here's the updated [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/vivekkupadhyay/pen/RGPyAE)

Updated **SCSS**:

```
.block__content {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.block__content {
    width: auto;
    height: 278px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.contenthover {
    bottom: -278px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.bgtile {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 278px;
    img {
        transform: scale(1);
        transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    }
    &:hover img,
    &:focus img{
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}
```

Updated **jQuery**:

```
$('.bgtile').mouseover(function() {
    $('.contenthover').css({
        bottom: '0'
    })
});

$('.bgtile').mouseout(function() {
    $('.contenthover').css({
        bottom: '-100%'
    })
});
```